WiFi not working after adding a loopback address to WiFi interface in Windows
I think I did something that I was not supposed to do.
While trying to learn something, I added a new loopback address to my WiFi interface in Windows without knowing what I'm doing. I typed the following:
netsh interface ipv4 add address name="Wi-Fi" source=static address=127.0.0.2 mask=255.0.0.0 gateway=127.0.0.2

It broke everything, internet connection is down. Of course, I don't know what I did. I deleted the address, but nothing happened. I searched up online some reset commands and I typed the following:
netsh int ip reset

And:
netsh winsock reset

Then after each restarted my computer, but nothing worked.
How can I reset to what it was before?
Right now, my computer has no access to my WiFi network. I mean, it finds it, it connects to it, but it's saying "No internet, secured". My WiFi network is working just fine. Also, I really want to know what did I do so that it broke everything?

Try netsh interface ipv4 delete address name="Wi-Fi". If this doesn't help, and if you have System Restore enabled, rollback to before you did this.

I uninstalled the wifi network adapter from device manager than I did a network reset from windows settings and it worked. Thanks!
